# Java not working on MacOS X Leopard

Tags: java, xcode, macos, profiling

I'm running Leopard, xcode 3.1.3.  When I type "java" at the command line I get this:

```
dyld: could not load inserted library: /usr/lib/libSaturnFE.dylib

Trace/BPT trap
```

What did I do?  I did do some profiling with Saturn a while back but I didn't know it was going to screw up my machine.  I'm fairly sure it worked when I first installed xcode.

I guess I could install a different Java SDK than the one that came with Xcode?  I can't find an upgrade path for Xcode that doesn't require me to upgrade to Snow Leopard.  I just don't feel like upgrading to Snow Leopard right now because I don't have good disk backups in place.

edit: at least if anybody could point me to a resource or even a Mac forum where I could ask this question it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  I forgot that I left this in my .profile:

```
export DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib/libSaturnFE.dylib
export DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE=1
```

The first of these two variables was causing a runtime override of system calls or something which was messing up java.